# Using reCaptcha in a Wordpress Page

Tags: php

All,
I've got a Page in Wordpress that I'm creating to allow some people to submit some feedback on to me. On my page I've got the following code to include the reCaptcha:

```
<?php
require_once('http://localhost/website/recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "12345"; // you got this from the signup page
?>
```

Then where I want the reCaptcha displayed I've got the following bit of code:

```
 <?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?><div id="captchaStatus"></div>
```

However, when I try and display this page I get the following error message from Wordpress:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function recaptcha_get_html()
```

Is there a better way to include the reCaptcha on a Wordpress page? I know there is a reCaptcha plugin but I believe that is only for pages with Comments on it which isn't my need here.

Do I need to not include it as a link and instead a path to the recaptcha page? If so, how can I do that from a page in Wordpress to my base folder?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you've written it this way for example purposes, but your `require_once` call is using a http request to try and include from, and as such I don't think your lib will be included correctly.

Try using the proper file path to the `.php` file you're trying to include, i.e. `local/path/to/file.php`.

The include path will look for local files on the disk - not make a http connection to a file.

For reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

I believe Wordpress specifies an `ABSPATH` constant in `wp-config.php` that you can use to get the root path of your WP install.

Comment: Is there a way to determine what the path to that file is?

Comment: Hi, just updated as you posted that comment, does that help you?