# reCaptcha in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, recaptcha

I have following codes for my comments page:

```
<?php 

$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

$comment_args = array( 'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(

//Author
'author' => '
            <div class="one_half_c">
             <label for="author"> something here </label> 
             <input id="author" name="commenter" type="text" value=" something here "/>
            </div>',

//Email
'email' => '
            <div class="one_half_last_c">
             <label for="email"> something here </label> 
             <input id="email" name="contact" type="text" value=" something here "/>
            </div>',)),

//Comment
'comment_field' =>'
            <div class="one_full_c">
               <label for="comment"> something here </label>
               <textarea id="comment" name="usercomm" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>     
            </div>',


'comment_notes_after' => '',
'title_reply' => ' something here ', 
'title_reply_to' => ' something here ', 
'label_submit' => ' something here ',
'id_submit' => 'sendemail',
); ?>
```

And this is one custom `<form>` for implementing reCaptcha from google:

```
<form action="?" method="POST">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-sitekey"></div>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I make it works for this page?

Also I read other questions like [Using reCaptcha in a Wordpress Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564006/using-recaptcha-in-a-wordpress-page) but they are different and irrelevant .